# QuestDB Use result of SELECT MIN (...) in WHERE

Tags: questdb

I would like to do something like this:

```
select *
from some_table t
where t.ts >= (select min(ts) from other_table)
    and t.ts <= (select max(ts) from other_table)
```

Is this somehow possible? I did not find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most databases, your current query is valid and should run.  If it does *not* happen to run on QuestDB, then you might try a join approach:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM some_table t
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(ts) AS min_ts, MAX(ts) AS max_ts
    FROM other_table
) o
WHERE t.ts BETWEEN o.min_ts AND o.max_ts;
```